# How to take the Xpath of last child element of a element in HTML?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have an html element code and here it is
[image]

Now I have choose the div with class = 'ui-widget-content slick-row even row_43'.
The 43 th row is the last row so next time when the application runs again the last will 
be 44 beacuse one more row will be added and I have to choose 44. How Can I choose the last row?

```
(//div[@class='slick-viewport'])[position() = 4]
```

above is the element of the highlighted part
I tried using

```
(//div[@class='slick-viewport'])[position() = 4]//following-sibling::div
```

but it didn't help
How can i get the element such that always the last div is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of position use `last()`

```
(//div[@class='slick-viewport'])[last()]
```

Comment: ((//div[@class='grid-canvas'])[last()])//div[contains(@class, 'ui-widget-content slick-row ')][last()]   this was wat I looking for!!!! Thanks